# Getting `TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum` while trying to connect to MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my connection String:

```
public static void connectToDatabase() {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.95\\instance;databaseName=sampleDB";
          
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "pass";

    try {
       Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
       System.out.println("Connected to sql server");                   
    }
```

I have never used MS SQL but i need to connect and this is error that i got:

```
avg 12, 2020 2:45:47 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
WARNING: TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. 
ClientConnectionId:33111bca-b8c7-4be3-9673-b012c5949817
```

I'm using windows 7 professional(don't ask). How can i fix this?

Comment: The fact that you are using 2 completely unsupported products is very much the underlying problem here. Time to upgrade both to supported versions

Comment: @Larnu it's company property :(. First is  i suppose from TLSv1 to TLSv1.2. What is second?

Comment: What version of SQL Server 2008 are you running?

Comment: *"it's company property"* Then time to get them to start paying out for supported software. TLS1.0 is a *huge* security risk, and SQL Server 2008 and Windows 7 haven't received any security updates for over a year and likely have known security risks as well.

Comment: @Larnu version is SQL Server 2008 r2. Well since covid junior developer jobs are none existing. I have to work here for now, it's my first day and can't connect to database. Can you help?

Comment: YOu've tagged SQL Server 2008, not 2008 R2 here. But I need to know the **full** version. What does `@@VERSION` give you?

Comment: @Larnu it's 10.50.1600.1

Comment: That's not what @@Version returns...

Comment: SQL Server version 10.50.1600.1 is SQL Server 2008R2 **RTM**! That means you haven't updated your server in over 10 years! YOU **need** to update that server, ASAP. No questions asked, no excuses. Thet server has **significant** security vulnerabilities. SQL Server 2008 RTM also does not support TLS1.2, so you **must** update it to be able to use it.

Comment: @Larnu Dude calm down :D I'm a java developer, some old dude is in charge of servers. I'm just here to make UI.

Comment: Note, to use TLS1.2 on SQL Server 2008, you need to update to SP3, which was released on October 25, 2011 (almost 9 years ago...).

Comment: There is no reason to be "calm" about having a server that hasn't seen a single update in over 10 years... That is just an exemplary example of incredibly poor server management, and  (in my professional opinion) a strong indication that the person is not fit for the role.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, this is company hold monopoly in my state and well owner dosen't want to pay to update server and other stuff.

Comment: updating a server (not upgrading) is free, it's part of the support of the product. Updating to SP3 doesn't cost anything. The fact that the server hasn't been updated (again in over a decade) just awful server management; there is no excuse for it.

Comment: @Larnu hey man, i want to install SP3 but installation won't proceed after 'support files'. It just exit from setup, no error nothing. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. I suspect that the server itself is incredibly out of date, so you likely have a decade's worth of updates to apply.

Answer (score 1):

In a Maven project you can change version in pom.xml like this;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning message 'WARNING: TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.' does not have anything to do with the connection exception.

Even with the warning, the connections would be established.
The issue in connection seems to be with the connection parameters.

Instead of

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.95\\instance;databaseName=sampleDB";
```

use

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.95;databaseName=sampleDB";
```

Also pass correct Username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this issue because my server password is expired